# JScrollBar visible

Tags: java, swing

Is there some way to know if a `JScrollBar` is visible or not inside a `JPanel`?

I mean, some times, my panel has many rectangles (think of it as buttons) and needs a scrollbar and some times it doesn't need it. I'd like to know if I can know when it is being shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you extend the `JPanel` and add yourself the `JScrollbar`s (horizontal and/or vertical), then you can control when they must be visible or invisible
(you can check if they are currently visible with the `isvisible()` function)

You can find two example of such classes that determine the need for visible scrollbar depending on their content:

- [`JGraphPanel`](http://www.koders.com/java/fid5EE718E124C09FC470BAB3864C3DE582A13DF458.aspx?s=jpanel+scrollbar+isvisible#L33) (its callback [`actionPerformed(Event e)`](http://www.koders.com/java/fid5EE718E124C09FC470BAB3864C3DE582A13DF458.aspx?s=jpanel+scrollbar+isvisible#L88) will adjust the visibility based on a zoom factor)
- [`Plane`](http://www.koders.com/java/fid8955059994F4F7A31D4860E61914F080BB4B2CC6.aspx?s=jpanel+scrollbar+isvisible#L23) (its function [`adjustComponents()`](http://www.koders.com/java/fid8955059994F4F7A31D4860E61914F080BB4B2CC6.aspx?s=jpanel+scrollbar+isvisible#L93) will call `setVisible()` on the `JScrollBar` if needed)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a reference to a `JScrollPane`, you should be able to just call

```
yourJScrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().isVisible()
```

or

```
yourJScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().isVisible()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need also to be notified about visibility changes than you can use a code as follows:

```
final JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(createMyPanel());
scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().addHierarchyListener(new HierarchyListener() {
  @Override
  public void hierarchyChanged(HierarchyEvent e) {
    if (e.getID() == HierarchyEvent.HIERARCHY_CHANGED && 
      (e.getChangeFlags() & HierarchyEvent.SHOWING_CHANGED) != 0) {
      System.out.println(scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().isVisible());
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: By wrapping the println with  "if(isShowing())", you will only be notified when the ScrollBar is actually visible on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Further to the answers by VonC and Joshua, it's worth noting that `isVisible()` is a method on the super class `Component`. Also, the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isVisible%28%29) states:

> Determines whether this component should be visible when its parent is visible. 
>   Components are initially visible, with the exception of top level components such as Frame objects.

What this means is that until the `JScrollPane` is added to a sized frame, calling `isVisible()` on the `JScrollBar` will *always* return `true`.

Consider the following SSCCE:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  // creates a small table in a larger scroll pane
  int size = 5; 
  JTable table = new JTable(makeData(size), makeHeadings(size));
  JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
  pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
  System.out.println(pane.getVerticalScrollBar().isVisible()); // prints true

  JFrame frame = new JFrame("JScrollPane Test");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setContentPane(pane);
  System.out.println(pane.getVerticalScrollBar().isVisible()); // prints true

  frame.pack();
  System.out.println(pane.getVerticalScrollBar().isVisible()); // prints false

  frame.setVisible(true);
  System.out.println(pane.getVerticalScrollBar().isVisible()); // prints false
}

private static Object[] makeHeadings(int size) {
  Object[] headings = new Object[size];
  for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
    headings[i] = i;
  }
  return headings;
}

private static Object[][] makeData(int size) {
  Object[][] data = new Object[size][size];
  for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<size; j++){
      data[i][j] = i*j;
    }
  }
  return data;
}
```

Similarly, it's worth adding that if you're adding the `JScrollPane` to an internal frame, then `scrollBar.isVisible()` will only work once the internal frame has been added to another component.